# Azure function : Appsetting.json is not working with Serilog.Sinks.Sumologic

Tags: c#, json, azure, appsettings, serilog

We are trying to implement logging using Serilog.Sinks.SumoLogic(1.0.1) to Azure function apps (without .NET core). Below is the code and appsetting.json we are using.

**Code:**

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

var loggerFromConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
               .CreateLogger();
```

**Appsettings.json:**

```
{"Serilog": {
 "MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "System": "Warning",
    "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "SumoLogic",
    "Args": {
      "endpointUrl": "https:"
      }
  }
  ]      
 }
}
```

With above appsetting we are not able to bind the sumologic sink with `loggerFromConfig` object and `_sinks = {Serilog.Core.ILogEventSink[0]}` which shows that there is no sink configured.

If we try the same code with a sample project with Microsoft.NET.Core.Apps dependency it is working fine.

It seems that appsettings.json is supported with .NET core apps only.

Please suggest how to write log using Serilog with `appsettings.json` (without .NET core apps).

Comment: Any update?If you feel my answer is useful /helpful.Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the ReadFrom.Configuration method is used to get the setting from appsettings.json in .net core project.

Since the ReadFrom.Configuration method needs IConfiguration object. If you want to use ConfigurationBuilder, you need install the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration package from the Nuget.

If you install this Nuget Package, you could use the ConfigurationBuilder class. But it will also install the Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms package.

In my opinion, the right way to use the Serilog in .net apps is using LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SumoLogic method like this.

```
   var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SumoLogic(url,
                                sourceName: "CustomSourceName",
                                sourceCategory: "CustomSourceCategory",
                                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug,
                                batchSizeLimit: 20,
                                period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                                textFormatter: new RawFormatter())
```

More details, you could refer to this [codes](https://github.com/billpratt/serilog-sinks-sumologic/blob/master/examples/Serilog.Sinks.SumoLogic.Sample/Program.cs).

Since the ReadFrom.Configuration method also read the setting from the appsettings.json file then using these setting to create LoggerConfiguration object, I suggest you could directly use the LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SumoLogic method.

Besides, if you still want to use appsettings.json, I suggest you could read the appsettings.json's setting by using [Newtonsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) package. Then you could pass these settings as parameters into LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.SumoLogic method.